# Why doesn't Debug.Log work in this for loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is what I have. This DrawPoints() method is called in an Update() method, meaning it is called repeatedly if it doesn't have extra conditions if I understand correctly. So basically I'm trying to make the for loop only run once by putting the outside `if (iTrack == 0)` check on it.

What is weird is that the Debug.Log commands will not run at all (the text `"Here  1"` or `"Here2"` never show up in Console), BUT the other code inside like `var lerpedPosition` and `whatToSpawnClone` run.

Why don't the Debug Log commands work? Is there something obviously wrong I'm doing with this code? This is very confusing.

```
int iTrack = 0;
int matricesNumber = 2;

public void DrawPoints()
{
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = mesh.vertexCount;

    float t = Mathf.Clamp((Time.time % 2f) / 2f, 0f, 1f);

    if (iTrack == 0) { 
        if (matricesNumber == 2)
        {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("Here 1");

                var lerpedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(matrices1[i].position, matrices2[i].position, t);
                whatToSpawnClone = Instantiate(whatToSpawnPrefab, lerpedPosition, matrices2[i].rotation) as GameObject;

                if (i == (endIndex - 1))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Here 2");
                    iTrack = 1;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of a side track question from me, but if you only plan to have the code run once why don't you have it executed inside a Start or Awake function so it's only ran once upon creation of the gameobject the script is attached to?

Comment: Would you please post a screenshot of your console?

Comment: @AlexMyers *considers deleting thread in shame* i had a search in the textbox. I'm going to bed.

Comment: @TimHunter Thank you. This inspired me now to separate code accordingly. I did not think to do that before your input.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited the question to reflect the actual problem. As it stands, this question isn't very useful to future readers.

Comment: Done, good tip! @RufusL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of your question I will assume that you are creating a script for Unity from here on out. Take a look at [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/757659/console-not-outputting-from-debuglog.html). It offers two solutions that would be worth a try, mainly the second one as it is as simple as a check to make sure you have Debug output enabled for the console.